# how to use Watermark property and RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, watermark

i use this code in aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" ToolTip="Email" Text="Email" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please insert email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="Email" ControlToValidate="Email" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but i use *Text="Search"* in textbox for use Watermark property in textbox. please help me for use Watermark property and RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: If I understand your question .. you are using regex to validate that the text is a valid email , and also using watermark that says "Search"  , and the watermark is making the textbox invalid ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox placeholder="Search" .... />
```

easy as that...  This is supported by all modern browsers , is there a reason you want to make it work with javascript?  Is it too support old IE?

and as far as the the string "Search" not passing validation - isn't that a good thing?? why would you want the form to be valid if they left the Default "Search" in the text box?

but anyways - if that is what you want you can change your regex like in the other answer , or you can do what Microsoft does and their watermark is "someone@email.com"

Comment: Still I recommend the placeholder attribute , i'll update answer to make a back up watermark for old browsers

Answer (score 0):

This will accept both "Email" and valid email address as valid tokens if thats what you're after:

```
<asp:TextBox ValidationGroup="Email" ID="Email" runat="server" ToolTip="Email" Text="Email" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Email';" onfocus="if (this.value=='Email') this.value='';"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please insert email" ValidationExpression="Email|(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)" ValidationGroup="Email" ControlToValidate="Email" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```